# nlpaug wordembeddings model not working PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '.'

Tags: python, nlp, data-augmentation

I am following these docs to try and do random word insertion: https://nlpaug.readthedocs.io/en/latest/augmenter/word/word_embs.html

However when simply trying to load the model I get an error:

```
import nlpaug.augmenter.word as naw

aug = naw.WordEmbsAug(model_type='word2vec', model_path='.', action='insert', aug_min=2, aug_max=4,
                  top_k=10, stopwords=stops)

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '.'
```

I don't understand this as I literally haven't changed anything and it's not working. Could someone explain please. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using spaces in the model path? ' . ' instead of '.'?

Comment: @AishwaryaPatange No there is no space in the model path.